# make input search box full screen overlay on click on mobile device

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I am using buefy autocomplete input fields in my nuxtjs project, this is location search box, what i want is just for mobile device, when i click the input field, it should overlay on full screen with suggestion like i attached screenshot below and after select suggestion, it should close and return to normal.

here is my simple auto complete input field code.

```html
<template>
  <b-autocomplete
    v-model="pickupairport"
    :data="airports"
    name="pickupairport"
    class="ttc-search-input"
    icon="map-marker-outline"
    placeholder="Pickup Airport"
    field="name"
    :loading="isFetching"
    @typing="getairports"
    @select="(option) => (aptselected = option)"
  >
    <template slot-scope="props">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-content">
          {{ props.option.name }}
          <br />
          <small> {{ props.option.cityName }}, {{ props.option.countryName }} </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pickupairport: '',
      airports: [],
      aptselected: null,
      isaptFetching: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getairports: debounce(function (pickupairport) {
      const aptsearchq = this.pickupairport
      if (!pickupairport.length) {
        this.airports = []
        return
      }
      this.isaptFetching = true
      fetch(`https://api.myurl.com/api/transfers/aplist?querystring=${aptsearchq}`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          this.airports = []
          data.response.forEach((item) => this.airports.push(item))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.airports = []
          throw error
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isaptFetching = false
        })
    }, 500),
  },
}
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is like this GIF - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr0PC.gif
What I have now is like this GIF - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkYHP.jpg

i tried to find something related, but couldn't find, if any suggestion on how to achieve that, it would be helpful for me.

Comment: Did you tried submitting the thing on `@keyup.enter.native`? What is not working in your case? The debounce, the style or the overall fetching? You shared a GIF vs an image.

Comment: @kissu - I edited my question with Gif vs Gif. please check the second gif that will make clear what i am looking. I just want to achieve Input search box behaviour like the first GIF in mobile device. When we click input box for search something, it should expand to full screen like the first GIF and then after selection of suggestion, it should be closed.

Comment: @kissu - why i should use keyup.enter.native to achieve that ! everything like debounce, ontyping, fetching is working, i just need that autocomplete box to be shown like first gif when focus to make it more mobile friendly similar to 1st gif image. i just don't know how to get that.

Comment: did you find it? I'm also stuck here like what is this functionality called so that I can search exactly on google to look other examples.